# Site cannot be loaded when using Deploy to Web app from VS Code

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

At work I'm using Visual Studios 2019 to publish my ASP.Net Core 2.1 App to the Azure App Service. At home I run a linux maschine and use VS Code to work on the project. Now I'm having trouble to deploy the app to Azure using 'Deploy to Web App' in VS Code. The process finishes successfully but when I open the url I get an 'IIS 502.5 Error - Process Failure'. Using Visual Studio this does not happen.

Before deploying the app I tried to build it using

```
dotnet build -c Release
```

with no success. I also tried

```
dotnet publish -c Release -f netcoreapp2.1 --no-self-contained
```

with no success too. Both commands followed by 'Deploy to Web App'.

Am I doing something wrong or do I miss some build-option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it myself. Found the solution [here](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/RightClickPublishQuicklyToAzureAppServicesWithVSCodeExtensionsAndZipdeploy.aspx).

You just have to set the `deploySubpath` to the directory where `dotnet publish` puts the generated files. In my case I had to set it to `project_1/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.1/publish`, which will be created by the command `dotnet publish -c Release`.

You can set the deploySubpath value in `Settings > Extensions > Azure App Service` or by editing the file `settings.json` in the `.vscode` directory. This directory will be created in the root directory of your workspace.

Be careful to always set the `deploySubpath` relatively to your `.vscode` directory. In my case my workspace looks like this

```
-- .vscode
:- project_1
`- project_2
```

where `project_1` is my ASP.Net Core project and `project_2` is a nodejs project.